# Wordpress: Change header code if user is logged in or out.

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm in the process of developing my own custom Wordpress template and upon building out the header.php file I decided I wanted to create two different headers. The first header will include a signup/login button and will be displayed if the user **is not logged in.** The second will include a profile image and name in place of the signup/login button and will be displayed if the user **is logged in.**

I have coded two separate headers, I just do not know how to write out the following properly:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //enter code here
} else {
    //enter code here
}
?>
```

Is this the right way to go about it? Or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: If you don't want to change the page they are in when logged in or out then *yes*.

Comment: You can go like this with one header template file with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Also try this:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
 // Not logged in.
} else {
// Logged in.
}
?>
```